# Streaming live stream with JWplayer in Phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, streaming, jwplayer

I have been at this for days and have had no luck with trying to trouble shoot.  So I have multiple live streams up on my site and I wanted to put this in an app but everytime I upload to phonegap and download on my phone the video wont play.

Neither the Flash or HTML5 version of the app plays.  I simply copied the code I used on the site to place in my index.html document of my app but for some reason it fails.  The message I get reads something like (going off memory) Either there was a problem with the network or server or this file is not supported).  Although I know that isnt the fact because it works when I view the site from my phone, just not the app.

Markup looks something like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.my-domain.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
div id='mediaplayer2'> 
                    <script type="text/javascript">  jwplayer('mediaplayer2').setup({
                       'id': 'playerID', 'width': '388',    'height': '218',
                    'provider': 'rtmp',  
                     'streamer': 'rtmp://0.0.0.0/some-directory',
                    'autostart': 'true',
                    'stretching': 'exactfit',

                            levels: [{
                                       bitrate: "800",
                                       file: "my-file-name",
                                       width: "1280"
                                   }],    
                    'modes': [
                           {type: 'flash', src: 'http://www.my-domain.com/jwplayer/player.swf'},
                           {
                             type: 'html5',
                             config: {
                              levels: [ {'file': 'http://0.0.0.0/some-directory/playlist.m3u8'} ],
                              'provider': 'video'
                             }
                           }
                       ]
                     });
                    </script>
                    <video
                          id="mediaplayer2"
                          controls="1"
                          autoplay="1"
                          height="218" 
                          preload="none"
                          src="http://0.0.0.0/some-directory/playlist.m3u8" 
                          width="388">
                        </video>
                        </div>
</body>
```

What do I need to do different to get this to work in an app like it does in my browser?  Im developing in Dreamweaver and even when I hit "Live" it streams perfectly, just not in app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't used PhoneGap much. Is there a way you can provide an example where this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use Vitamio Player it can play all kind of streaming also its open source,. u just need to include this as library into ur project and make sure to use vitamio videoview or mediaplayer,. k no worry take a look at this Sample to include Vitamio into ur project

Hope its Helps you,.

Regards
Rajeev